# Faster alternative to grouby/shift

Tags: python, pandas

File under the general heading of "groupby is slow if you have a large number of groups"

```
nobs =   9999 

df = DataFrame( { 'id' : np.arange(nobs) / 3,
                  'yr' : np.tile( np.array([2007,2008,2009]), nobs/3 ),
                  'val': np.random.randn(nobs) } )

df = df.sort(['id','yr'])

A = df.groupby('id').shift()
B = df.shift()
```

A is what I want, but it takes about 1.5 seconds here, and my actual use case has about 100x the observations.  For reference, calculating A is about 1000x slower than calculating B.

Here's what A and B look like:

```
In [599]: A.head(6)
Out[599]: 
        val    yr
0       NaN   NaN
1 -0.839041  2007
2 -1.089094  2008
3       NaN   NaN
4 -0.068383  2007
5  0.555293  2008

In [600]: B.head(6)
Out[600]: 
   id       val    yr
0 NaN       NaN   NaN
1   0 -0.839041  2007
2   0 -1.089094  2008
3   0  0.050604  2009
4   1 -0.068383  2007
5   1  0.555293  2008
```

I'd love a general solution to speeding up A, but absent that, a workaround would be great.  As you can see, B is actually the same as A except the first value of each group is not really valid and needs to be converted to NaN.  It could be done with groupby/rank but anything involving groupby seems to be slow, so I need a non-groupby method.

Is there some way to replicate the rank function via the sorting or indexing?  It seems like the information must be embedded there, but I don't know how I'd extract it to a new variable.

(Edited to add the following)

Here's a solution from the link provided by Jeff below (original answer by HYRY).  I've just altered it slightly to work with the example here.  On my computer it runs at almost exactly the same speed as DSM's solution.

`B.iloc[df.groupby('id').size().cumsum()[:-1]] = np.nan`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't the most elegant piece of code ever, but as a hack workaround for your case, how about something like:

```
def fast(df, col):
    A = df.sort(col).shift()
    last = A.iloc[-1].copy()
    A.loc[A[col] != A[col].shift(-1)] = np.nan
    A.iloc[-1] = last
    return A.drop(col, axis=1)

def slow(df, col):
    A = df.sort(col).groupby(col).shift()
    return A
```

which gives

```
>>> %timeit s = slow(df, "id")
1 loops, best of 3: 2.09 s per loop
>>> %timeit f = fast(df, "id")
100 loops, best of 3: 3.51 ms per loop
>>> slow(df, "id").equals(fast(df, "id"))
True
```

Comment: note that the groupby and shift is implemented in python ATM - needs cythonization to be fast - open issue is here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4095

Comment: similar method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401197/how-to-speed-up-pandas-multilevel-dataframe-shift-by-group

Comment: @Jeff  So shift outside of groupby is cythonized but inside of groupby is not?

Comment: @DSM  I'm still holding out hope for something more general, but thank you, that's pretty good.  Is there any way to prevent the np.nan line from applying to the very last line of data?  That would save 2 lines.

Comment: ATM this is the best way to do this. a pull request to cythonized the groupby would be appreciated. the actual shift code is just creating and using an indexer so it is quite fast itself (and would not benefit from cython). groupby needs to avoid processing in python space so essentially would create thrn indexer (eg what you are using in the loc, but for the general non sorted case). nothing to hold out.

Comment: @Jeff  Thanks, this is mostly going over my head now, but I'll try to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 20, 15, 30, 45,43,67,22,12,14,54],
                   'B': [13, 23, 18, 33, 48, 1,7, 56,66,45,32],
                   'C': [17, 27, 22, 37, 52,77,34,21,22,90,8],
                   'D':    ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','c']
                   })
df
#>      A   B   C  D
#> 0   10  13  17  a
#> 1   20  23  27  a
#> 2   15  18  22  a
#> 3   30  33  37  a
#> 4   45  48  52  b
#> 5   43   1  77  b
#> 6   67   7  34  b
#> 7   22  56  21  c
#> 8   12  66  22  c
#> 9   14  45  90  c
#> 10  54  32   8  c
def groupby_shift(df, col, groupcol, shift_n, fill_na = np.nan):
    '''df: dataframe
       col: column need to be shifted 
       groupcol: group variable
       shift_n: how much need to shift
       fill_na: how to fill nan value, default is np.nan 
    '''
    rowno = list(df.groupby(groupcol).size().cumsum()) 
    lagged_col = df[col].shift(shift_n)
    na_rows = [i for i in range(shift_n)] 
    for i in rowno:
        if i == rowno[len(rowno)-1]: 
            continue 
        else:
            new = [i + j for j in range(shift_n)]
            na_rows.extend(new) 
    na_rows = list(set(na_rows)) 
    na_rows = [i for i in na_rows if i <= len(lagged_col) - 1] 
    lagged_col.iloc[na_rows] = fill_na
    return lagged_col
```

the result gives:

```
    
df['A_lag_1'] = groupby_shift(df, 'A', 'D', 1)
df
#>      A   B   C  D  A_lag_1
#> 0   10  13  17  a      NaN
#> 1   20  23  27  a     10.0
#> 2   15  18  22  a     20.0
#> 3   30  33  37  a     15.0
#> 4   45  48  52  b      NaN
#> 5   43   1  77  b     45.0
#> 6   67   7  34  b     43.0
#> 7   22  56  21  c      NaN
#> 8   12  66  22  c     22.0
#> 9   14  45  90  c     12.0
#> 10  54  32   8  c     14.0
```