# pandas: setting last N rows of multi-index to Nan for speeding up groupby with shift

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to speed up my groupby.apply + shift and 
thanks to this previous question and answer: [How to speed up Pandas multilevel dataframe shift by group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401197/how-to-speed-up-pandas-multilevel-dataframe-shift-by-group)  I can prove that it does indeed speed things up when you have many groups.

From that question I now have the following code to set the first entry in each multi-index to Nan. And now I can do my shift globally rather than per group.

```
df.iloc[df.groupby(level=0).size().cumsum()[:-1]] = np.nan
```

but I want to look forward, not backwards, and need to do calculations across N rows. So I am trying to use some similar code to set the last N entries to NaN, but obviously I am missing some important indexing knowledge as I just can't figure it out.

I figure I want to convert this so that every entry is a range rather than a single integer. How would I do that?

```
 # the start of each group, ignoring the first entry
 df.groupby(level=0).size().cumsum()[1:]
```

Test setup (for backwards shift) if you want to try it:

```
length = 5
groups = 3
rng1 = pd.date_range('1/1/1990', periods=length, freq='D')
frames = []
for x in xrange(0,groups):
    tmpdf = pd.DataFrame({'date':rng1,'category':int(10000000*abs(np.random.randn())),'colA':np.random.randn(length),'colB':np.random.randn(length)})
    frames.append(tmpdf)
df = pd.concat(frames)

df.sort(columns=['category','date'],inplace=True)
df.set_index(['category','date'],inplace=True,drop=True)
df['tmpShift'] = df['colB'].shift(1)
df.iloc[df.groupby(level=0).size().cumsum()[:-1]] = np.nan

# Yay this is so much faster.
df['newColumn'] = df['tmpShift'] / df['colA']
df.drop('tmp',1,inplace=True)
```

Thanks!

Comment: to remove all the pandas and complexity, at the heart of the problem I think I want to change this list:
    
     a=[5,10,18]

to

     b=[3,4,8,9,16,17]

ie replace each item X in a list with X-N, X-N+1, ... X-1.

where a is the result of this df.groupby(level=0).size().cumsum()[:-1] from the original question

Comment: OK.  Btw, I went ahead and deleted all my comments/answers since they were apparently not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it using a groupby apply as follows (and coded to work forwards or backwards):

```
def replace_tail(grp,col,N,value):
    if (N > 0):
        grp[col][:N] = value
    else:
        grp[col][N:] = value
    return grp

df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(replace_tail,'tmpShift',2,np.nan)
```

So the final code is:

```
def replace_tail(grp,col,N,value):
    if (N > 0):
        grp[col][:N] = value
    else:
        grp[col][N:] = value
    return grp


length = 5
groups = 3
rng1 = pd.date_range('1/1/1990', periods=length, freq='D')
frames = []
for x in xrange(0,groups):
    tmpdf = pd.DataFrame({'date':rng1,'category':int(10000000*abs(np.random.randn())),'colA':np.random.randn(length),'colB':np.random.randn(length)})
    frames.append(tmpdf)
df = pd.concat(frames)

df.sort(columns=['category','date'],inplace=True)
df.set_index(['category','date'],inplace=True,drop=True)
shiftBy=-1
df['tmpShift'] = df['colB'].shift(shiftBy)
df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(replace_tail,'tmpShift',shiftBy,np.nan)

# Yay this is so much faster.
df['newColumn'] = df['tmpShift'] / df['colA']
df.drop('tmpShift',1,inplace=True)
```

Comment: Note that the requirement to do a sort eats into the effectiveness of this, but its still faster than doing the shift per group.  Especially if you need to do multiple calculations with different shifts, as the sort only needs to be done once.